# BeautifulSoup - extracting texts within one class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract texts from this webpage below:

```
<div class="MYCLASS">Category1: <a id=category1 href="SomeURL" >
Text1 I want</a> &gt; Category2: <a href="SomeURL" >Text2 I want</a></div>
```

I tried:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='MYCLASS'):
    for url in soup.find_all('a', id='category1'):
        print(url)
```

And it returned:

```
    <a href="someURL" id="category1">Text1 I want</a>
```

So I split the text...

```
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='MYCLASS'):
        for url in soup.find_all('a', id='category1'):
            category1 = str(url).split('category1">')[1].split('</a>')[0]
            print(category1)
```

and extracted "Text1 I want", but still miss "Text2 I want". Any idea? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

There are other < a> < /a> in the source code, so if I remove `id=` from my code, it would return all other texts that I don't need. For examples,

```
<div class="MYClass"><span class="Class">RandomText.<br>RandomText.<br>
<a href=someURL>RandomTextExtracted.</a><br>
```

Also,

```
</div><div class=MYClass>
<a href="SomeURL>RandomTextExtracted</a>
```

Comment: You're specifically getting all links that have id `category1` but `Text2 I want` doesn't have that id.

Comment: @JackRyan, I recognized so, that's why I couldn't extract Text2 I want. What do you think might help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the `id='category1'` from the `find_all()`.

Comment: Thanks @KeyurPotdar, but there are other <a> in the source that it would extract all other texts that I don't want if I only leave with [find_all('a')]. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `id` of an element is unique, you can find the first `<a>` tag using `id="category1"`. To find the next `<a>` tag, you can use [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method.

```
html = '''<div class="MYCLASS">Category1: <a id=category1 href="SomeURL" >Text1 I want</a> &gt; Category2: <a href="SomeURL" >Text2 I want</a></div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

a_tag1 = soup.find('a', id='category1')
print(a_tag1)    # or use `a_tag1.text` to get the text
a_tag2 = a_tag1.find_next('a')
print(a_tag2)
```

Output:

```
<a href="SomeURL" id="category1">Text1 I want</a>
<a href="SomeURL">Text2 I want</a>
```

<sup>(I've tested it for the link you've provided, and it works there too.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You need a your code a little

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<div class=\"MYCLASS\">Category1: <a id=category1 href=\"SomeURL\" > \
Text1 I want</a> &gt; Category2: <a href=\"SomeURL\" >Text2 I want</a></div> \
I","lxml")
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='MYCLASS'):
    for url in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(url.text.strip())
```

Remove id for 'a' tag and run the same code.

If you need text of specify ids, you need to know the ids.

```
ids = [id1,id2]
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='MYCLASS'):
    for id in ids:
        for url in soup.find_all('a',id=id):
            print(url.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks @bigbounty. What if there are other classes with the same name "MYCLASS"? When I run your code, it returns Text1 and Text2 that I want, but also other texts that I don't want. How would you extract that? Thank you.

Comment: You say that you don't want , and you want to extract it!?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just added more info in the question. So, there are some other classes that share the same name `MYCLASS` as the targeted one. But the only text that I want to extract is from Category1 and Category2.

Comment: Make a list of wanted ids. Loop through the wanted ids and put the id in id tag in your code and run it

Comment: there are 2 Texts that I want to extract from the same id `id=category1`. But it would return only Text1, not Text2. I'm trying to extract `Text1` (after Category1) and `Text2` (after Category2).